# Cannot install Hostapd in Porteus (Slackware)

Tags: linux, wifi-configuration, portable, slackware, hostapd

I’m trying to install hostapd (to share laptop’s Wi-Fi) into Porteus (I guess it’s a slackware based distro). I’ve tried `usm -s hostapd`, it said:

> driver_nl80211.c:21:31: warning: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or
>   directory

Then [I found this](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd/) and install `libnl-1.0pre8` (I don’t know whether I did it right or not) but anyway I have this error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/netlink/genl/genl.h:15:0,
                 from ../src/drivers/driver_nl80211.c:19:
/usr/local/include/netlink/netlink.h:27:29: fatal error: linux/ip_mp_alg.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/ip_mp_alg.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../src/drivers/driver_nl80211.o] Error 1
```

So what should I do to install hostapd properly?

Answer (score 0):

you need a newer libnl. libnl3 should be fine http://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware-current&p=libnl3-3.2.21-i486-1.txz